# How to render googleLogin in react 18.2.0

Tags: reactjs, react-google-login

I have an issue about GoogleLogin component in react. Here is my code:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { Avatar, Button, Typography, Paper, Grid, Container } from "@mui/material";
import { GoogleLogin } from "react-google-login";
import LockOutlinedIcon from "@mui/icons-material/LockOutlined";
import Input from "./Input";
import Icon from "./icon";
import { useDispatch } from "react-redux";
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";

import useStyles from "./styles";
import { Password } from "@mui/icons-material";


const Auth = () => {
    const classes = useStyles();
    const [showPassword, setShowPassword] = useState(false);
    const [isSignup, setIsSignup] = useState(false);
    const dispatch = useDispatch();
    const navigate = useNavigate();

    const handleSubmit = () => {

    };

    const handleChange = () => {

    };

    const handleShowPassword = () => setShowPassword((prevShowPassword) => !prevShowPassword);

    const switchMode = () => {
        setIsSignup((prevIsSignup) => !prevIsSignup);
        handleShowPassword(false);
    };

    const googleSuccess = async (res) => {
        const result = res?.profileObj;
        const token = res?.tokenId;

        try {
            dispatch({ type: "AUTH", data: { result, token } });

            navigate('/');
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error);
        }
    };

    const gooleFailure = () => {
        console.log("Google Sign In was unsuccessful. Try again later");
    };

    return (
        <Container component="main" maxWidth="xs">
            <Paper className={classes.paper} elevation={3}>
                    <Avatar className={classes.avatar}>
                    <LockOutlinedIcon />
                    </Avatar>
                <Typography variant="h5">{isSignup ? 'Sign Up':'Sign In'}</Typography>
                <form className={classes.form} onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
                    <Grid container spacing={2}>
                        {isSignup && (
                            <>
                                <Input name="firstName" label="First Name" handleChange={handleChange} autoFocus half />
                                <Input name="firstName" label="First Name" handleChange={handleChange} half />
                                <Input name="lastName" label="Last Name" handleChange={handleChange} half />
                            </>
                        )}
                        <Input name="email" label="Email Address" handleChange={handleChange} type="email" />
                        <Input name="password" label="Password" handleChange={handleChange} type={showPassword ? "text" : Password} handleShowPassword={handleShowPassword} />
                        {isSignup && <Input name="confirmPassword" label="Repeat Password" handleChange={handleChange} type="password" />}
                    </Grid>
                    <Button type="submit" fullWidth variant="contained" color="primary" className={classes.submit}>
                        {isSignup ? 'Sign Up' : 'Sign In'}
                    </Button>
                    <GoogleLogin 
                        clientId="CLEINT ID" 
                        render={(renderProps)=>{
                            <Button className={classes.googleButton} color="primary" onClick={renderProps.onClick} disabled={renderProps.disabled} startIcon={<Icon />} variant="contained">
                                Google Sign In
                            </Button>
                        }}
                        //buttonText="Google Sign In"
                        onSuccess={googleSuccess}
                        onFailure={gooleFailure}
                        cookiePolicy="single_host_origin"
                    >
                    </GoogleLogin>
                    <Grid container justify="flex-end">
                        <Grid item>
                            <Button onClick={switchMode}>
                                { isSignup ? 'Already have an account? Sign In' : "Don't have an account? Sign Up" }
                            </Button>
                        </Grid>
                    </Grid>
                </form>
            </Paper>
        </Container>
    );
}

export default Auth;
```

For somehow reason I cant see the google sign in button in my website. When I open console, it always shows 'Google Sign In was unsuccessful. Try again later'

which is wired, it means it logs in failed, but I dont even see the login button.
I have already set up the right client id but I didn't put it there. So it cant be the reason. I also try to use return outside the render in googleLogin component. But it still doesn't work.